# Unable to connect to MySQL 5.7 server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

My server was working great and all of sudden I began getting the following errors. I am not able to access my DB through phpmyadmin either. This is a new issue for me and I am a bit confused with all of the information that is out there.:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log expire_logs_days        = 10 max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Comment: Is your mysql server running? Check your mysql log at /var/log/ and see what's up.

Comment: Here is the result of when I check the status of MySQL Server:
Uptime: 2289  Threads: 1  Questions: 6  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 105  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 98  Queries per second avg: 0.002

Comment: @JNevill I went back in for the the first time, since yesterday. I checked the status of mysql server and it was running. I was then able to start and stop and restart the server and login. I have no idea why I was having so many issues yesterday.